# Получение двух очередей из одномерного массива в c#

Tags: c#

Есть такая проблема:нужно из массива получить четные и нечетные значения в две строки, а не чередованием четной и нечетной.Как мне это осуществить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[] array = new int[11];
            array[0] = 0;
            array[1] = 1;
            array[2] = 2;
            array[3] = 3;
            array[4] = 4;
            array[5] = 5;
            array[6] = 6;
            array[7] = 7;
            array[8] = 8;
            array[9] = 9;
            array[10] = 10;
            for(int i=0;i<array.Length; i++)
            {

                if ((i % 2) == 0)
                {
                  Console.WriteLine("Четное число массива " + array[i]);
                }

                else 
                    Console.WriteLine("Нечетное число массива " + array[i]);
            }



            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) создать ещё 2 массива куда сложишь значения по условию, а затем напечатаешь 2) сделать два разных цикла `for` с разным условием на вывод

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем понял, что вам нужно, но предположу два варианта:

**Для удобства:**

Сделаем для начала разделение всех чисел на два массива (по сути можно попробовать и без этого, но там в разы упрощается вся задача!):

```
var even = array.Where(x => x % 2 == 0);
var odd = array.Where(x => x % 2 != 0);
```

**Выводить четные и затем нечетные:**

Делается это путем прохода по каждому списку циклом:

```
foreach (var i in even)
    Console.WriteLine($"Четное число массива :{i}");

foreach (var i in odd)
    Console.WriteLine($"Нечетное число массива :{i}");
```

Результат:

> Четное число массива :0
>   Четное число массива :2
>   Четное число массива :4
>   Четное число массива :6
>   Четное число массива :8
>   Четное число массива :10
>   Нечетное число массива :1
>   Нечетное число массива :3
>   Нечетное число массива :5
>   Нечетное число массива :7
>   Нечетное число массива :9

**Вывод массива в одну строку:**

Тут либо формируете строку циклом, либо делаете костыль с добавлением в строку через `Console.Write()`, либо используем что то по типу `string.Join()` - этот метод выводит значение массива в одну строку, разбивая указанным символом:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Четные числа массива: {string.Join(",", even)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Нечетное числа массива: {string.Join(",", odd)}");
```

Результат:

> Четные числа массива: 0,2,4,6,8,10
>   Нечетное числа массива: 1,3,5,7,9

В общем выбирайте сами что именно вам нужно.
Удачи в изучении C#!

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array = Enumerable.Range(0, 11).ToArray();

        StringBuilder sbEven = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbOdd = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var num in array)
        {
            if (num % 2 == 0)
            {
                sbEven.Append($"{num}, ");
                continue;
            }

            sbOdd.Append($"{num}, ");
        }

        string even = sbEven.Replace(',', '.', sbEven.Length - 2, 1).ToString();
        string odd = sbOdd.Replace(',', '.', sbOdd.Length - 2, 1).ToString();

        Console.WriteLine($"Четные: {even}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Нечетные: {odd}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать и так:

Делаем extension-метод, который позволит нам в будущем разбить `IEnumerable` на две части по предикату:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Split<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    yield return source.Where(predicate);
    yield return source.Where(x => !predicate(x));
}
```

Затем используем этот метод:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

var splittedArray = array.Split(x => x % 2 == 0);
var even = splittedArray.ElementAt(0); //четные
var odd = splittedArray.ElementAt(1); //нечетные

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", even));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", odd));
```